# Nginx's location path is redirecting me when trailing slash is removed

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Here is my reverse proxy configuration.

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.access.log  main;
  root /usr/share/nginx/htdocs;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location /apps/ {
    proxy_pass  http://our-amazon-s3-bucket/apps/;
  }
}
```

When I visit http://amazon-elb-fqdn/apps/, I see the webpage properly.

However, when I visit it this way(notice the missing trailing slash), http://amazon-elb-fqdn/apps, it fails and the url on my browser location changes to http://amazon-elb-fqdn:8080/apps

Why does that happen? What is the fix for it?

UPDATE: April 15, 3:15 Central Timezone

When I access the s3 url directly like this, http://our-amazon-s3-bucket/apps, the s3 bucket will redirect me correctly to http://our-amazon-s3-bucket/apps/

Comment: What's listening on port 80?

Comment: I don't have any server config for "listen 80". The only config I have is the above which is 8080. What should I add? Btw, I edited my post by changing localhost to amazon-elb-fqdn. What we really access is an amazon load balancer(elb) which is listening on port 80 publicly. It forwards the requests to the nginx server listening on port 8080 hence my port 8080 configuration.

Comment: What if I add a new config like this? location /apps { proxy_pass  http://our-amazon-s3-bucket/apps; } I removed the trailing slash from the location and proxy_pass. Will this help?

Comment: `port_in_redirect off;`

Comment: Ok Alexey, I'll try that too

Comment: Hi Alexey Ten, I tried it too but still didn't work.

Comment: Actually, looks like there is nothing really wrong with my configuration. When I cleared my cache and restarted the browser, I don't get the issues anymore. Looks like it was a local cache issue.

Comment: I tried it again and moved it to server block. Still didn't work

Comment: Here is my latest config, still no joy - https://p.ngx.cc/58

Comment: I added an update to my latest post. I just mentioned how s3 bucket responds

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to take care of location mapping. So here is fix for you

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.access.log  main;
  root /usr/share/nginx/htdocs;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location ~* ^/apps/ {
    rewrite ^/apps/(.*) /$1 break;       
    proxy_pass  http://our-amazon-s3-bucket/apps;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try that now Harshad! :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get back with you. I tried your suggestion but it failed when I reloaded nginx. Here is the error - nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:113

Comment: @devwannabe can you try this solution now? I have edited the config.

Comment: will do. I'm close to work. I'll let you know

Comment: it still didn't work

Comment: This is how I configured amazon and nginx - http://imgur.com/TTM2Id8

Comment: @devwannabe can you try this last one.

Comment: ok, trying it now

Comment: got this error with that new config - nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:115